# Save checklist progress without user accounts

Tags: javascript, jquery, forms, web-frontend

I've been asked to create a simple checklist for a client's website. This checklist contains pre-defined items. Users must be able to hide/ignore items of their choosing (a simple checkbox or cross) and users must be able to check whether the item is completed. Of course, it must look nice, be printable etc. etc. So far so good.

However, the idea is that this checklist is usable by every visitor (without user account) and those visitors must be able to save their progress, to load it during another visit. I am unsure how to safely include this (must-have) functionality.

My approach currently is to set the checklist up in a form and (somehow) make it possible to save the forms state with a button. This would download a file to the user’s computer (.json, .csv). But in this scenario the user would also have to upload the file back onto the website (preferable drag and drop), in turn the file would be read into the form and re-initiate the saved state.

EDIT: As advised in the comments, for single user cases localStorage is a great option. But there are cases for multiple users to work on the same checklist (at different times). Is for those cases a save/export function still the only option?

- Is my thinking correct that if I build this purely front-end (JavaScript + jQuery) I am not introducing a security risk for the site and its users?
- Is this approach possible and/or is it advisable? If no, are there good alternatives?

Comment: If you are using TLS with your website you are not introducing any vulnerability. The approach you are describing is not at all advisable. You should google up on ways to store data in the users browser.

Comment: If you're not worried about legacy browsers, you can use LocalStorage. They could set the key as a unique identifier and keep the data stored in it.

Comment: LocalStorage is a very good addition which i will definitly use for single user cases. What i forgot to mention because I had this approach in mind is that the checklist's state is to be shared with multiple users (but far less often than a single user). Will update the question.

Comment: For multiple users I would suggest a database in which you can save the data for all users by IDs and then have the website send the correct list when one visits list.tld/someId